# Add event on Layer border - vue leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, border, polygon, layer

How can I add an event to the polygon border, if the user clicks inside the polygon it should do nothing, but if the user clicks on the border it should trigger some event, is it possible?

Comment: Can you post some code of what have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import ttk as ttk
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Section Analysis')
root.geometry('700x400')
root.state('zoomed')

polygon1 = Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]])

x,y = polygon1.exterior.xy

fig = Figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=100)
rects1 = fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x,y,color ='tab:blue',picker=True, pickradius=5)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    print('onpick points:', points)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
    
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).